beautifulsoup converting string into html name codes ('<' into '&lt;', etc.) with UTF8 encoding
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("test/test.html", 'rt', encoding='UTF8'), 'html.parser', from_encoding='UTF8')
text = "<p>exampletext</p>"  
soup.body.append(text)  
with open("test/result.html", "w", encoding='UTF8') as file:
          file.write(str(soup))
print(str(soup))

above outputs:
&lt;p&gt;exampletext&lt;/p&gt; 

I opened an html file with Korean characters using beautifulsoup (the korean characters are not properly decoded without a specified encoding) and while that did successfully read the html file, when I tried appending a string with html tags with an append function, the tags in the string are converted into the html name codes  ('<' into '<', etc.). I read people saying its the encoding that is creating this issue, but I don't know how to open the html file in python making sure that the korean characters are intact. Is there a way I can fix this?

add a new tag instead of raw html

instead of
text = "<p>exampletext</p>"  
soup.body.append(text) 

create a new tag:
p = soup.new_tag('p')
p.string = 'exampletext'
soup.body.append(p)

